# Docker convenience script stuck after "Scanning linux images"

Tags: docker

I have a Raspberry Pi 2B and a fresh install of Raspbian.

I am trying to install Docker, and following the instructions on the site (https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/#install-using-the-convenience-script), I used the convenience script just like it's written there.

This is all the output I get:

```
# Executing docker install script, commit: 26ff363bcf3b3f5a00498ac43694bf1c7d9ce16c
+ sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
+ sh -c DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -qq apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl >/dev/null
+ sh -c curl -fsSL "https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian/gpg" | apt-key add -qq - >/dev/null
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
+ sh -c echo "deb [arch=armhf] https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian buster stable" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
+ sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
+ [ -n  ]
+ sh -c apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends docker-ce >/dev/null
Scanning processes...                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Scanning linux images...
```

I let it run for more than a half hour and nothing changes.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Just found this question from 5 days ago because I ran into the same thing on a RPi 4, also using the convenience script.

Just waiting a bit did not seem to help. So I killed the process after a while. And Docker is running just fine, now.